# Randomize Lines order in textbox with StringBuilder

Tags: vb.net, stringbuilder

I'm trying to randomize the final Result here the idea is get the textbox lines do some code , then export it to textbox2 , the code is working but i want to randomize the lines order when exporting to textbox2

```
        Dim newr As New StringBuilder
           For Each line In texbox1.text.Lines
           newr.AppendLine(line & " CODE-DONE-1")
           newr.AppendLine(line & " CODE-DONE-2")
           newr.AppendLine(line & " CODE-DONE-3")

        Next
    textbox2.text = newr.ToString 'Want to randomize Lines Order
```

Example
if i put in textbox1

```
1
2
3
```

i want the output in textbox2

```
3 Code-Done-1
1 Code-Done-3
2 Code-Done-2
3 Code-Done-3
1 Code-Done-1
3 Code-Done-2
2 Code-Done-3
```

Comment: @JQSOFT i don't  fully understand your question i'm kinda newbie to vb.net can you put it in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class level variable of Random type:

```vb
Imports System.Linq
'//

Private ReadOnly rand As New Random
'//
```

Using the `StringBuilder` with `For..Loop` way:

```vb
Dim sb As New StringBuilder

For Each line In TextBox1.Lines.
    Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).
    OrderBy(Function(x) rand.Next)
    sb.AppendLine($"{line} Code-Done")
Next

TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString
```

The `OrderBy(Function(x) rand.Next)` part will shuffle the lines of the first text box and display them in the second one..

Alternatively, you can use the extension methods to achieve that in just one line:

```vb
TextBox2.Lines = TextBox1.Lines.
    Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).
    OrderBy(Function(x) rand.Next).
    Select(Function(x) $"{x} Code-Done").ToArray
```

So choose the appropriate way for you.

---

According to your edit, if you want to *append* the outputs, replace the `StringBuilder` with a class level variable of `List(Of String)` type and edit the code as follows:

```vb
Imports System.Linq
'//

Private ReadOnly rand As New Random
Private ReadOnly output As New List(Of String)

'//

For Each line In TextBox1.Lines.
    Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    output.Add($"{line} Code-Done")
Next

TextBox2.Lines = output.OrderBy(Function(x) rand.Next).ToArray
```

Comment: You need to choose one of them, I just posted more than one way to achieve that,

Comment: i don't get the idea here , i want to Randomize sb.ToString Line order , i can't see how it can be done with your code

Comment: @lolee This `OrderBy(Function(x) rand.Next)` will do the trick. It will shuffle the lines of the first text box and display the output in the second text box as you requested.

Comment: @lolee Make sure you have this on the top `Imports System.Linq`

Comment: @JQSOFT i think u didn't understand me so i updated my question , there's can me multiple  ` sb.AppendLine($"{line} Code-Done")` of same line , i want to shuffle sb.ToString because it's the last one , your code will shuffle income lines , then do nothing , i want to Shuffle the **END lines after coding**

Comment: @JQSOFT your code will get them to order only incoming lines shuffled but sb.ToString not shuffled because there's repeated `sb.AppendLine(line code)`

Comment: @JQSOFT u still not understanding me , if i have 3lines in textbox1 after i do my code it will be 9 lines , i want to shuffle 9 lines , with your answer it will be not shuffling anything just the first 3lines

Comment: @lolee  The last code will do what you want. You can't use a `StringBuilder` for this task. A `List(Of String)` is. Try the last code block and forget the rest. This `TextBox2.Lines = output.OrderBy(Function(x) rand.Next).ToArray` will randomize the order of the entire list whether it contains 9 lines, less or more.